# Netbeans 12 on Windows won't let me connect Tomcat

Tags: windows-10, tomcat8, catalina, java-14, netbeans-12

No matter which tutorial I follow, I am unable to get apache-tomcat-8.0.9 to work with Netbeans 12. The IDE keeps showing the error message `The specified Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid`. I'm using jdk-14.0.1 and apache-ant-1.9.15.

The error:
[image: The Error Message]

My Catalina home directory C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.9
[image: My Catalina home directory C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.9]

Perhaps this error testing tomcat from the command line has some clues?
[image: Perhaps this error testing tomcat from the command line has some clues?]

Comment: Maybe Netbeans is choking on the space in the Tomcat path ("Program Files"), could you try installing Tomcat in another directory (e. g. C:\tomcat)?

Comment: Tomcat 8 is ancient and unsupported. I ran into similar problems at my job: older Tomcat versions sometimes just completely break when running on a too recent JRE. Either downgrade to JRE/JDK 8, or (better) upgrade to a newer Tomcat, and there is a decent chance of the problem going away.

Comment: @Taschi it's annoying how simple that solution was. I tried Tomcat 9.0.37 and it worked with no problems. The thing is I'm just setting up my work environment on my new computer and decided to use the new Netbeans. The rest of the dev team is using the old NetBeans and old tomcat and everything, so I was trying to use the old tomcat with the new IDE to make sure our work would be compatible. I may end up having to downgrade to be able to work with the rest of the team. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the last link from the question try this:
In file nbproject/project.properties try to change this line (it may contains other path)

```
endorsed.classpath=\
    ${libs.javaee-endorsed-api-7.0.classpath}
```

to this:

```
endorsed.classpath=
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way:

Go to the folder of Tomcat and enter, the system tells me that I don't have rigths, and if I want enter? I select yes. The system displays the content of the folder. I try again to conect netbeas with tomcat and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by created `CATALINA_HOME` environment variable. For creating `CATALINA_HOME` in environment variable specify the path of `catalina.bat` file in tomcat folder installation without bin folder.

Ex: if you have `catalina.bat` in `C:\Program Files\Apache\Tomcat\bin\catalina.bat`, then specify in `CATALINA_HOME` just `C:\Program Files\Apache\Tomcat` as path.